# How to provide parameter to url containing colon

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 to make some REST api calls in my app. However, there are some api's which have endpoints like `/profile/:id` i.e. they contain colons in the endpoint. I need to provide `:id` at runtime to make api call. This seems similar to url's which contain paths for e.g. `/profile/{id}`, for which documentation is present at official page of [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). However, I cannot find anything for url's containing colon. So, is there anyway I can do this in retrofit?

Comment: My guess is that the URL doesn't contain a colon. The *documentation* for the URL contains a colon. AFAIK, a colon is not a valid path character. `/profile/:id` would be just another way of documenting the same thing as `/profile/{id}`, meaning that the second path segment gets replaced at runtime by the appropriate value.

Comment: Ok. I'll try it using `@Path`.

Comment: Yup! Your suggestion worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find an example usage for that kind of endpoints in **retrofit**

```
@GET("profile/{id})
Call<UserProfile> getProfile(@Path("id") int userId);
```

Hope it covers your needs

Answer (score 1):

If you come here because your url parameter contains ":" or "("

in itself like **"skills:(android-app-development)"**:

`https://www.upwork.com/ab/feed/jobs/atom?&q=skills:(android-app-development)&sequrityToken="blablabla"`

Try using [dynamic links](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests) in retrofit:

Since normal request string with params like:

```
@Query("&q") String q4,
@Query("&securityToken") String q5,
```

is broken by this ":" or "(".